# JDK doesn't support Java FX; netbeans

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I've attached a screenshot. I was trying to open and run a template to get a feel for java graphics. Should I download a different JDK version?[image: Screenshot]

I've tried youtube and google for answers.

Comment: JavaFX hasn't been part of the JDK since version 11 (possibly earlier, but I only look at long-term support versions, so 11 comes after 8).   You need to install JavaFX separately.

Comment: Documentation is in [getting started at openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).  The easiest way is the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html) in Idea.  Recent JDK versions which include JavaFX are available, [setup Zulu JDK FX in Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69633235/why-cant-idea-find-javafx-package-after-upgrade-javafx-project-to-jdk-17-using/69636003#69636003), but not necessarily needed.  Ensure that whatever IDE and other software that you use is up to date.

Comment: See the video [How To install JDK 17 and JavaFX 17 on NetBeans IDE](https://youtu.be/VGlD8uJGJl8) and [the related article](https://kensoftph.com/how-to-instal-jdk-17-and-javafx-17-on-netbeans-ide/).

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

Download either *ZuluFX* or *LibericaFX* as your JDK/JRE.

## Details

[JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) has never been a part of standard [Java SE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Standard_Edition).

Modern JavaFX is implemented in the OpenJFX project led by [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/) and [Oracle Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation).

To write and deploy a JavaFX app you must either:

- Include a copy of the OpenJFX libraries within your app, or
- Use a JDK that comes bundled with the OpenJFX libraries.

At least two vendors currently offer a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit)/[JRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform)#Java_Runtime_Environment) with [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/) bundled:

- [*ZuluFX*](https://www.azul.com/downloads/#zulu) by Azul Systems
- [*LibericaFX*](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) by BellSoft